# Postgresql installation issues on OS X

Tags: mac-osx, installation, postgresql

I used Fink to install postgresql on os x.  when i try to start psql, i get:

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I have never installed postgresql before so I am not really sure where to look.  Have any suggestions?

Comment: +1 for just asking the question. I've been thinking of using PostgreSQL on my mac.

Comment: +1 for just *mentioning* PostgreSQL, my database of choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That means the PostgreSQL daemon is not running.  You'll want to find where the daemon is installed.  By default, it should be installed in /usr/local/pgsql.  If it's there, inspect to see if there is a /usr/local/pgsql/data directory.  If there is not run the following:

/usr/local/pgsql/bin/initdb -D /usr/local/pgsql/data

then, if successful, run

/usr/local/pgsql/bin/pg_ctl -D /usr/local/pgsql/data start

And that should get you on the right track.

Comment: i get an error on initDB. "fixing permissions on existing directory /Library/PostgreSQL/8.4/data ... initdb: could not change permissions of directory "/Library/PostgreSQL/8.4/data": Operation not permitted" ....looking into it.  let me know if you know how to fix this.  thanks

Comment: So most likely you're trying to execute the command as your user but PostgreSQL is already setup with a different user.  From this i would guess you can: ls -al /Library/PostgreSQL/8.4/data to find the user who owns it and then do a sudo su username -c 'pg_ctl -D /Library/PostgreSQL/8.4/data start'

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me, you're trying to run PostgresSQL under your current user-account.
I don't know the fink-properties for PostgreSQL, but the associated daemons are supposed to run under a dedicated user-account (lets say *postgres* for example).

First identify the data-directory, in which PostgresSQL stores it's data and configuration files exist. Your error messages seems to say this may be "/Library/PostgreSQL/8.4/data".
This directory should belong already to the *postgres*-user and have rwx-privileges for him.
I guess Fink has already created it, so check out the install-logs.

Look inside this directory (you may need to su/sudo because you may not have sufficient privileges to do so with your console user). If there are some files, eg. postgresql.conf, a bunch of pg_* and some other files, all belonging to *postgres*, the data directory seems to be allright, otherwise invoke the following (replace the binary-path, *postgres*-user and the data path with your system-values, see man initdb for more options):

```
sudo -u postgres /usr/local/pgsql/bin/initdb  -D /Library/PostgreSQL/8.4/data
```

It's **important** to sudo as the postgres user here, because the user-account the postgres deamons runs as will have to have the sufficients access-rights.

Also, you will have to start the deamon with the the sudo (this should later be handled by a lauchctl-entry, or something similar), so:

```
sudo -u postgres /usr/local/pgsql/bin/pg_ctl -D /Library/PostgreSQL/8.4/data
```

You can always re-create the data-directory, but be sure to make a backup and do not overwrite it when postgres is still running.

Answer (score 1):

You can check that Postgresql is running and listening with:

`lsof -i |grep LISTEN`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though you don't have the server started, and possibly haven't run [initdb](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime.html)

If you have more trouble, though, the easiest (and recommended by postgresql) way to install postgresql on Mac OS X is via the GUI installer provided by [EnterpriseDB](http://www.enterprisedb.com/products/pgdownload.do#osx).  It even handles installing multiple versions quite nicely.

Comment: the enterpriseDB installation claimed to fail.  said could not initialize the cluster. my guess it that it was a permissions issue when running initDB so i am trying to do that manually now